# How to hide the black console window of Selenium that appear before opening chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to hide the black console window of Selenium that appear before opening chrome and surfing the website  Any Idea ?

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DODemo1.UserControls
{
    public partial class DashboardUC : UserControl
    {
        public DashboardUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://website.com");

        }

    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Hmmmm isn't it Selenium doing that not _"Visual Studio"_?

Comment: yup Selenium , so can i have an idea what should i do to hide this black console ?

Comment: Look at the links provided above

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
this.driverServiceProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

to your code.

Comment: It's Selenium Chrome Driver doing it not that the app may be a console app or not

Comment: yup Selenium , so can i have an idea what should i do to hide this black console ?

Comment: @Dr.Mezo Try other answered that are related.

Comment: I had edited this answer to match Selenium.